# How to move the textbox caret to the right

Tags: c#, textbox, keypress

I would like to change all the characters entered into a textbox to upper case. The code will add the character, but how do I move the caret to the right?

```
private void textBox3_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    textBox3.Text += e.KeyChar.ToString().ToUpper();
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: what GUI framework are you using? Is this win forms? wpf? silverlight?

Comment: @monkey_boys-I hope my changes left your meaning intact.

Comment: Note that `textBox3.Text += e.KeyChar.ToString().ToUpper()` will always add the new character last in the text box, even if the caret is in the middle of the text.

Comment: @John macIntyre- I think he meant that he wants the cursor to be at the right side of the newly inserted character.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Set the [`CharacterCasing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.charactercasing.aspx) property of the `TextBox` to `Upper`; then you don't need to process it manually.

Note that `textBox3.Text += e.KeyChar.ToString().ToUpper();` will append the new character to the end of the string *even if the input caret is in the middle of the string* (which most users will find highly confusing). For the same reason we cannot assume that the input caret should appear at the end of the string after inputting the character.

If you would still really want to do this in code, something like this should work:

```
// needed for backspace and such to work
if (char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)) 
{
    return;
}
int selStart = textBox3.SelectionStart;
string before = textBox3.Text.Substring(0, selStart);
string after = textBox3.Text.Substring(before.Length);
textBox3.Text = string.Concat(before, e.KeyChar.ToString().ToUpper(), after);
textBox3.SelectionStart = before.Length + 1;
e.Handled = true;
```

Comment: +1: I provided an alternative answer as it can be useful in other situations.

Answer (score 13):

```
            tbNumber.SelectionStart = tbNumber.Text.ToCharArray().Length;
            tbNumber.SelectionLength = 0;
```

Comment: This is a great way to add text before the user types.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void txtID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtID.Text = txtID.Text.ToUpper();
    txtID.SelectionStart = txtID.Text.Length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will preserve the location of the insertion point (but persionally I'd go with the answer given by Fredrik Mörk)

```
private void textBox3_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)    
{        
    int selStart = textBox3.SelectionStart;
    textBox3.Text += e.KeyChar.ToString().ToUpper();        
    textBox3.SelectionStart = selStart;
    e.Handled = true;  
}
```

SelectionStart might actually be called SelStart, I don't have a compiler handy at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to do this manually, you can use

```
private void textBox3_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    textBox3.Text += e.KeyChar.ToString().ToUpper();
    textBox3.SelectionStart = textBox3.Text.Length;
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

But the preceding code inserts the new character at the end of the text. If you want to insert it at where the cursor is:

```
private void textBox3_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    int selStart = textBox3.SelectionStart;
    textBox3.Text = textBox3.Text.Insert(selStart,e.KeyChar.ToString().ToUpper());
    textBox3.SelectionStart = selStart + 1;
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

This code inserts the new character at the cursor position and moves the cursor to the left of the newly inserted character.

But i still think setting CharacterCasing is better.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to just change the value of the KeyChar itself:

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
        if ((int)e.KeyChar >= 97 && (int)e.KeyChar <= 122) {
            e.KeyChar = (char)((int)e.KeyChar & 0xDF);
        }
    }
```

Although, using the CharacterCasing property is the easiest solution.